# How to call onCreate method from other class?

Tags: android, oncreate

I want to call onCreate(Bundle cicici); from other class then i am getting "NullPointerException", so please guide me how can i call the onCreate() from another class.

Comment: Simple answer you can't :( you have to call the activity

Comment: sorry i am new to java.so ple give me a example code

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is only one way in which onCreate can be called, by starting an Activity, since onCreate is as part of Activity life cycle.

```
 startActivity(new Intent(presentActivity.this, NextActivity.class));
```

Comment: I want to show my second activity inside first activity.the above intent to show another screen.

Comment: You want to change the layout?

Comment: you cannot have two Activities on top of the stack at the same time. I guess you'll have to redesign your activity to incorporate the information of both activities in a single activity.

Comment: Can you call the onStart then? Or is there any way to reload a previously created activity to refresh the contents of it without having to call it again, because that takes time.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to call onCreate in order to actually present a new screen, then you need to create a the new Activity using the android framework style.

Ingredients:

1- An event to call your new activity( ie. onClickListener of a Button or list triggered)
2- On the event you need to create an Intent with the reference of the current activity and a [class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html) reference of your new Activity, example:

```
Intent intent =new Intent(CurrenActivity.this, MyNewActivity.class);
```

3- You need to call this activity depending on what you'll need you use startActivity or startActivityForResult, the last is use when you expect a response from your activity.

You can also refer to [Android documentation Common Task](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html), let us know if its helpful

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to do in the second activity. If you want to create a simple task you can always use dialogs and you can show them inside your activity. 
Or, on a second thought, you can hide some of your views and enable others but I guess that's not an orthodox solution :)